# Python function for plotting a heatmap

Tags: python, function, heatmap

I'm having a hard time making a function that plots a Heatmap when I call it for several variables.

Here's what I managed to do so far, which works very well, but how can I make it into a function?

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ypos', 'xpos', 'val'])

df.loc[0] = [1,1,MD.at[0,"VarName[1][1]"]]
df.loc[1] = [1,2,MD.at[0,"VarName[1][2]"]]
df.loc[2] = [1,3,MD.at[0,"VarName[1][3]"]]
df.loc[3] = [1,4,MD.at[0,"VarName[1][4]"]]
df.loc[4] = [2,1,MD.at[0,"VarName[2][1]"]]
df.loc[5] = [2,2,MD.at[0,"VarName[2][2]"]]
df.loc[6] = [2,3,MD.at[0,"VarName[2][3]"]]
df.loc[7] = [2,4,MD.at[0,"VarName[2][4]"]]
df.loc[8] = [3,1,MD.at[0,"VarName[3][1]"]]
df.loc[9] = [3,2,MD.at[0,"VarName[3][2]"]]
df.loc[10] = [3,3,MD.at[0,"VarName[3][3]"]]
df.loc[11] = [3,4,MD.at[0,"VarName[3][4]"]]
df.loc[12] = [4,1,MD.at[0,"VarName[4][1]"]]
df.loc[13] = [4,2,MD.at[0,"VarName[4][2]"]]
df.loc[14] = [4,3,MD.at[0,"VarName[4][3]"]]
df.loc[15] = [4,4,MD.at[0,"VarName[4][4]"]]

print(df)
ax = sns.heatmap(df.pivot('ypos', 'xpos', 'val'), annot=True)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Please note that VarName[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBPQ1.jpg) ... VarName[4][4] is the header name of each column in the dataset.

I'd really appreciate your help!!

Comment: The VarNames so far are just zeros, so please ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def heatmap(VarName):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ypos', 'xpos', 'val'])
    i = 0
    for x in range(1,5):
        for y in range(1,5):
            tempVar =  (VarName + "["+str(x)+"]["+str(y)+"]")
            df.loc[i] = [x,y,MD.at[0,tempVar]]
            i = i + 1
    ax = sns.heatmap(df.pivot('ypos', 'xpos', 'val'), annot=True)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set_title(VarName)

heatmap("VarName")  # note the strings " "
```

This outputs the same heatmap as above plus a title, but from a function.